# Maven deploy cant create directories

Tags: maven

Whenever I try and do a maven deploy it can't seem to create directories and I need to do this manually.

Any idea why this might be?

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=quickfixj  -DartifactId=quickfixj-all
-Dversion=1.5.2  -Dpackaging=jar  -Dfile=/dev/quickfixj/quickfixj-all-1.5.2.jar   -DrepositoryId=maven-repo   -Durl=https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/MYREPO/maven -X

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact quickfixj:quickfixj-all:jar:1.5.2 in maven-repo (https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/MYREPO/maven) -> [Help 1]
```

However if I manually create the directories quickfixj>quickfixj-all>1.5.2 it works fine.

Comment: Most likely a permission issue.  When you log into the repo to create the directories manually are you using the same user?